# Disallow panning completely away from world map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is there a way to restrict panning inside a Mapbox container, such that you cannot completely hide the world by panning, when `renderWorldCopies` is set to false? If you zoom out completely on a map, you are able to pan the map to either side until it is completely hidden. How do I disallow this and make the map stay inside the container?

I have tried adapting the example from the [MapBox GL JS documentation on restricting map panning area](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/restrict-bounds/) by setting the bounds to `[[-90, -90], [90, 90]]`:

```js
var bounds = [
  [-90, -90], // Southwest coordinates
  [90, 90]    // Northeast coordinates
];

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
  center: [-73.9978, 40.7209],
  zoom: 3,
  renderWorldCopies: false,
  maxBounds: bounds
});
```

This gets me part of the way, but restricts the panning area too much and cuts off some of the world when zoomed out all the way:

[Screenshot of map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVd1o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera position is the position that is limited by that example. Thereby you can see more than the area within the panning limits.

The limits you have chose indeed cut off half of the world. 
Please try with these bounds, they should solve this problem:

```js
    var bounds = [
   [-180, -90], // Southwest coordinates
   [180, 90]    // Northeast coordinates
    ];
```

Comment: Your suggestion helped. I can now zoom out all the way to see the whole world from west to east, and I can no longer pan the world out of the container. Is it possible to zoom out enough that I can see the whole world from north to south also and east to west inside the container?